# How to access to node on form_submit

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I added a button to the page. I'm trying to get the values of the field when I click the button. But I can not understand how to access the node from submit? Am I on the right track or should I look for another solution? I tried to add $node to the function redirect_button_form_submit but this does not work.

```
function show_on_map_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    $url = url(current_path(), array('absolute' => TRUE));
  if (($node->type == 'addproblem') && (strpos($url, "problem"))) {
    $form = drupal_get_form('redirect_button_form');
    $node->content['redirect_button'] = $form;
 }
}

function redirect_button_form($form, &$form_submit) {
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Show on map'),
    );
    return $form;
}

function redirect_button_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
//How to access the $node here?

    $geofield = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_location_exif');
    $location = array(lat => $geofield[0][lat], lon => $geofield[0][lon]);
    $path = '<front>';
    $options = array('query' => $location);
    drupal_goto($path, $options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the node as an argument to your form builder and store it there.

```
$form = drupal_get_form('redirect_button_form', $node);


function redirect_button_form($form, &$form_state, $node) {       
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Show on map'),
    );

    return $form;
}


function redirect_button_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $node = $form_state['build_info']['args'][0];

    $geofield = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_location_exif');
    $location = array(lat => $geofield[0][lat], lon => $geofield[0][lon]);
    $path = '<front>';
    $options = array('query' => $location);
    drupal_goto($path, $options);
}
```

[drupal_get_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7.x) can take additional arguments besides $form_id.

> Any additional arguments are passed on to the functions called by
>   drupal_get_form(), including the unique form constructor function. For
>   example, the node_edit form requires that a node object is passed in
>   here when it is called.

Also, to do a form redirect you can use:

`$form_state['redirect'] = path...`

Instead of drupal_goto which should not be used here.

> When $form_state['redirect'] is an array it should be populated with
>   arguments appropriate for drupal_goto() - which is to say, the second
>   element in the array can itself be an array holding all the properties
>   expected by url()'s $options argument, including fragment, query,
>   absolute, etc.

Comment: Oh, and I overlooked this - you should not use drupal_goto to do a form redirect. Set the path with `$form_state['redirect'] = path...`.